# How can I generate a Composer author list from Git's commit history?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

How can I make sure that a package's `composer.json` file has the correct list of authors, as extracted from the Git log? An author should be included if e has more than five commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple(-ish) one liner:

```
git log --format='{"name": "%aN", "email": "%aE"},' | sort |  uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '$1 > 5 {$1=""; print $0}'
```

To explain:

1. Get the list of all commits, but only show the author's name and email address (in the format required for `composer.json`
2. Sort this, to make sure all commits by the same author are grouped together
3. Filter this to only unique lines, and append a count
4. Sort again, this time by the appended count
5. Finally print only those lines where the count is greater than five, and exclude the count field in the final output